# Не работает переход по ссылке

Tags: flash, actionscript

Во флеше есть код такого рода `navigateToURL(request, "_self");` Если страница сайта, на котором находится флеш, начинается на www - то ссылка не работает. Если стрница без www - то работает. С параметром `"_top`" работает и в том и в другом случае. С параметром "`_parent`" - та же проблема. Нужно, чтобы переход по ссылке происходил в текущем окне.

Comment: А без флеша, в браузере в обоих случаях работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант в лоб: убирать из ссылки "`www`".

Кстати, чего она начинается с "`www`", где "`http:\\`"?

Comment: Если набираю в браузере например http://site.ru/ - то ссылка работает. Если http://www.site.ru/ - не работает

Comment: ну вот, флеш оказался не при чем :)